# How does the double asterik operator work here?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I understand that how `*` and `**` operators generally work. In the following code [ taken from django's source ]

```
def curry(_curried_func, *args, **kwargs):
    def _curried(*moreargs, **morekwargs):
        return _curried_func(*(args + moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
return _curried
```

I get how the `args + moreargs` part work - the [non - keyword ] arguments passed initially to the function `curry` and the arguments passed to the curried function returned by `curry` are combined. What I don't get is how the `**dict(kwargs, **morekwargs)` works. Could someone please explain that bit?

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/python-once-and-for-all-what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python

Comment: @limelights I read it just now. As I mentioned in my post, I understand [ hopefully :) ] how the `**` operator works. My doubt is with the `**dict(kwargs, **morekwargs)` part.

Comment: Yeah, i totally misread it, but left it for good FYI. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict(kwargs, **morekwargs)` is a trick (that Guido [dislikes](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099459.html)) for combining 2 dictionaries into 1.

```
>>> d = {'foo':'bar'}
>>> kwargs = {'bar':'baz'}
>>> dict(d,**kwargs)
{'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 'baz'}
```

So, the curried function takes all kwargs passed to `curry` and adds them to the additional kwargs passed to the `_curried` function to create a super dictionary.  that super dictionary gets unpacked and sent on to the `_curried_func`.

Comment: Reference for the "Guido dislikes" part: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099459.html

Comment: @Aya -- After re-reading that, maybe "dislikes" wasn't strong enough... :).  Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @mgilson Thank you, and personally I find dict.update method to be much more easier on the eyes :)

Answer (score 1):

It effectively builds a union of two dicts, `kwargs` and `morekwargs`. Example:

```
>>> kwargs = {"ham": 1, "spam": 2}
>>> morekwargs = {"spam": 3, "eggs": 2}
>>> dict(kwargs, **morekwargs)
{'eggs': 2, 'ham': 1, 'spam': 3}
```

This works because the `dict` constructor takes keyword arguments, so it's the same as

```
>>> dict(kwargs, spam=3, eggs=2)
{'eggs': 2, 'ham': 1, 'spam': 3}
```

Finally, the resulting `dict` is fed as keyword arguments to `_curried_func` by means of `**`.